# C# Interface class and object dependencies AND design issue (code separation)

Tags: c#, oop, interface

First day on the job I got handed down guy's code who is no longer at the company. An intern got his hands on the code before I did and really did a number on it! 
So here is the situation.

```
Project A

namespace A{
    public class Evil { ... }
    public interface A1 { 
        Evil[] Evils
        {
            get;
            set;
        } 
        Evil getSomeEvilValue();
    }

    public class Hello : A1{
        public void some_func(){
            // reference to Project B 
            B.World w = new B.World();  // <--- Dependency on B!! Thank you intern!
            w.Run();
        }

        #region A1 implementation
        Evil[] evils;
        Evil[] Evils
        {
            get{return evils;}
            set{evils = value;}
        } 
        Evil getSomeEvilValue(){return new Evil();}
        #endregion
    }  
}
```

in another project B

```
Project B
    namespace B{
    public class World{
        public void Run(){
            ...
        }
    }  
}
```

New requirements specify that Project B has to interface with A1!! This will create circular reference! So I thought the solution will be by creating a 3rd project, Interfaces, and changing A and B to reference the new one.

But the question is how do I deal with the A1's dependencies on class Evil??

```
Project Interfaces
namespace Interfaces
{
    public interface A1
    {
        Evil[] Evils   // <---- what do i do here?? IEvil? 
        {
            get;
            set;
        } 
        Evil getSomeEvilValue();  // <----- What do i do here???
    }
 }
```

Thanks heaps for your help guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Inversion of Control

1. Extract the interfaces to a project that A and B know -> AB-Interfaces
2. Create a Project that is the entry point for the application, it stands for the so called "Composition root" - here you reference A and B and you pass the references to the classes (so B would request A in the constructor, as property,...) and A would request B (not also in the constructor otherwise you will have a circular dependency again ;)

You could also do this with a DI controller but for now this would do it.

See a code example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

In your code:

```
Project A
namespace A {
        public class Hello : A1{
            public Hello(IWorld world){
                w.run(this);
            }
    }
}

Project B
namespace B {
    public class World : IWorld {
        public run(A1 a1){
            ...
        }
    }
}

Project I
namespace I {
    public interace A1{}
    public interface IWorld { run(A1); }
}

project Comp
namespace Comp {
    public class AppEntry {
        IWorld w = new World();
        A1 a1 = new Hello(w);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is correct way to do it, DI is most suitable for such scenarios

Comment: @MrWombat thanks for the info. What do I do with the interface's dependencies on class Evil? I thought of using templates so instead of Evil[] Evils .. I could have something like T[] Evils<T> ... but can't get it to work :(

Comment: you could a) put Evil in another project (if its some application wide thing or so) or b) create an abstract for it and use this in project I (this could also be an abstraction from .Net itself, most people don't think about this option). If you can't use one of these option i think you will have to put evil in the I project... that would not be that bad since everyone has to use that class in your interface (it is bound to that class so referencing the interface can include Evil)

Comment: Including class Evil in the Interfaces project will solve the problem, but is that a good design decision? Again, thank you heaps MrWombat, I'm doing the changes on my side now...

Comment: no ... note that you should (if possible) allways program against interfaces and not implementations. therefor you should also have an Interface IEvil and the interface AI should reference an array of IEvil instead or better yet an IEnumerable<IEvil>

Comment: creating an abstraction that is only used once introduces complexity and you need to use two references but gives you testability (you can mock it) and future extensibility - but its up to you if Evil is a candidate for that...

Comment: Thanks heaps MrWombat and @Florian-Schmidinger. The IWorld Interface initiated by a 3rd party did the job. Thanks for the help guys